# How to correctly define DTO attributes

Tags: java, spring, dto

I have to implement a parking system in Java using Hibernate and Spring.

I have already implemented the server side of the application (the connection to the database and the business layer using Hibernate) and now I am trying to implement the client side. I am trying to code the UI requests part of the application (add request feature: a user selects one of his cars and a parking lot for which he would like to get a parking spot reserved) and I use a hardcoded DTO list for the requests data.

My question is, is this how you would define a DTO class for this purpose?

```
import lombok.Data;
import java.util.Date;

@Data
public class RequestDTO {
    private final String status;
    private final Date date;

    public RequestDTO(String status, Date date){
        this.status = status;
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

Or like this?

```
import lombok.Data;
import java.util.Date;

@Data
public class RequestDTO {
    private final String status;
    private final Date date;
    private final ArrayList<ParkingLotDTO> parkingLots;
    private final ArrayList<CarDTO> cars;

    public RequestDTO(String status, Date date, ArrayList<ParkingLotDTO> parkingLots, ArrayList<CarDTO> cars){
        this.status = status;
        this.date = date;
        this.parkingLots = parkingLots;
        this.cars = cars;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. What is this DTO used for? If, as I understand, it's used to send a request containing a chosen car and a chosen parking lot, all you need is a car ID and a parking lot ID in the DTO. If it's used to contain all the selectable cars and all the selectable parking lots, then you need that in your DTO. In any case, I don't see how a status and a date have anything to do with the problem you described.

Comment: @JBNizet they are used for the request, as in the date the request has been created and its status (pending, approved, denied)

Comment: The request to do what? Who sends the DTO to who, and to do what?

Comment: @JbNizet the user creates a request, which is sent as a DTO to the UI, to be shown in a table

Comment: That still doesn't answer my question. Does it contain data that is sent from the UI to the server, or from the server to the UI? And why is it sent? To do what? A DTO should contain the information that is necessary to achieve what you want to achieve. If it's used by the UI to book a specific parking lot for a specific car on the server, then it needs to contain a parking lot ID and a car ID. If it's used by the server to send a list of parking lots to the UI so that the UI can display these parking lots, then it needs to contain the list of parking lots to display.